# Fade Out and Fade the whole screen having tabbar controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uianimation

I am having `tabbarController` in my app, which is consistent over the app, and i have respective `viewcontroller` attached to the `tabbarItem`, so on one of the `viewcontroller1` i am having a `ClickMeButton` on its click i am presenting `viewController2`, before presenting the `viewController2` i want an fade out the whole screen to white which includes `tabbar` `statusBar` also and when the animation gets over want to present the `viewController2` and again when user clicks another `Button` i want to fade in and dismiss the `viewcontroller`.

Thanks in advance.
I haven't worked much with the animation, please do help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did somthing like this:

```
UIWindow *statusWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
statusWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
statusWindow.hidden = NO;
statusWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[statusWindow makeKeyAndVisible];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
          [statusWindow setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0]];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
            statusWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [statusWindow release];
        }];
```

I hope this helps someone. :-)